# Regression: what to do with categorical predictors?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, k-nearest-neighbour

I've got a few categorical predictors (like gender,...) and now I want to
build regression models. So I've made the categorical predictors numeric
by for example: "female" --> 1 and "male" --> 0.

But when I do methods like nearest neighbors regression I have to standardize
all the predictors (for example the weights). What to do here with the categorical
variabels (that were made numeric)? Does this also have to be standardised? This seems
so weird.

Silke

Comment: In R, you can cast categorical predictors as factors. Factor coding has the advantage of taking care of the problem of breaking multiple levels of categories into binary features automatically. R's regression routines will parse and interpret these correctly as categories when fitting the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by mike seems good..
when you have a categorical variable, better to convert it into a 1-0 dummy variable, even if it has more than two levels(say k levels), like male/female/other then you should create k-1 dummy variables. I agree these variables don't need any standardization.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn the categorical predictors into values such as (0,1) you **do not** need to further standardize them. However, if you had something like (0,1,2) you should then scale these to (0,0.5,1).

If you are using R (caret package) or python (scikit-learn library) there are some standard libraries that will take of this for you.

Comment: can you explain why do you need to scale variables with more than 2 levels between [0,1] instead of using 0,1,2,..?

Comment: This is incorrect, because a trichotomous categorical variable cannot be represented adequately by a single numerical value.  See the threads on categorical variables and dummy coding.